# multiple string() results for an xpath?

Tags: xpath

```
string()
```

works great on a certain webpage I am trying to extract text from.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=lemons&first=111&FORM=PERE

has similar structure. For bing, the xpath I have tried is

```
string(//h3/a)
```

which works great to get the search results, even with strong tags etc, but only returns the first result. Is there something like strings(), so I can get the full text of each

```
//h3/a
```

result?

Comment: In what way are you querying with XPath?

Comment: Python lxml + https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/, both give the same result, the query being string(//h3/a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something like strings(), so I can get the full text of each
>
> ```
> //h3/a
> ```
>
> result?

**No, Not in XPath 1.0**.

From the **[W3C XPath 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string)** (the only normative document about XPath 1.0):

> "Function: string string(object?)
>
> The string function converts an object to a string as follows:
>
> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>   the node in the node-set that is first in document order."

So, if you only have an XPath 1.0 engine available, you need to select the node-set of all `//h3/a` elements and then in your programming language that is hosting XPath, to iterate on each node and get its string value separately.

**In XPath 2.0 use**:

```
//h3/a/string()
```

The result of evaluating this XPath 2.0 expression is a sequence of strings, each of which is the string value of one of the`//h3/a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN documentation of `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133.aspx) remarks that:

> The `string()` function converts a node-set to a string by returning the string value of the first node in the node-set, which in some instances may yield unexpected results.

This sounds like what you are experiencing. Why are you using `string()` at all?

Use `//h3/a/text()`

Comment: I am using string() because the html inside the a tag is something like "blah <strong>blah 2</strong> blah 3", which text() doesn't pick up as a single string. The desired result is "blah blah 2 blah 3" for each //h3/a