# Excluding child elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I've a parsed XML string in JS, data comes from the wikipedia api and looks like this:

```
<part>
    <name>
        Other names   
    </name>=
    <value> * Some  * other * Names ([[IUPAC]])
        <ext>
            <name>
                ref
            </name>
            <attr/>
            <inner>
                {{SomePaper|3283|Datum=20. November 2014}}
            </inner>
            <close>
               &lt;/ref&gt;
            </close>
        </ext>
        * Last name
    </value>
 </part>
```

I want to use XPath to just extract all the names = no child nodes of `<value>`. I parse the XML with

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
```

and then try to extract with

```
var result = doc.evaluate("//name[contains(text(), 'Other names')]/following-sibling::value[not(self::ext)]", doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

Yet the output is something like `* Some * other * Names ([[IUPAC]])ref{{SomePaper|3283|Datum=20. November 2014}}</ref> * Last name`

One thing that kind of works is

```
var result = doc.evaluate("//name[contains(text(), 'Other names')]/following-sibling::value[not(self::ext)]/text.()", doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
```

But then I'm loosing everything that comes after the `</ext>` = "* Last name" is missing (the reason for that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192105/select-nodevalue-but-exclude-child-elements#comment11568434_9192746) I think).

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v03xqoq4/1/

My desired output:

> *Some *other *Names ([[IUPAC]]) * Last name

Comment: What exactly would you like to output to be? Please _show_ it.

Comment: Well, this bit is clearly nonsense: `following-sibling::value[not(self::ext)]` because an element named `value` will never satisfy the predicate `self::ext`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mathias, updated my question (also with a fiddle). Fair point @MichaelKay, thanks for your help. But I still don't have a clue how to solve my problem :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
var iterator = doc.evaluate("//name[contains(text(), 'Andere Namen')]/following-sibling::value[1]/text()", doc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

  while (thisNode) {
  console.log( thisNode.textContent );
  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  } 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryv72mqm/2/

Thank you @Mathias Müller for getting me there!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following expression is what you need:

```
//name[contains(text(), 'Other names')]/following-sibling::value[1]/text()
```

Applied to the input XML you show, the result is (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
* Some * other * Names ([[IUPAC]])
-----------------------
* Last name
```

As you can see, the expression returns two individual results, whereas you'd like to result to be a concatenated string, which you cannot do with XPath 1.0. But I assume you can use a JS string function to concatenate the results.

Now, some more details that might be helpful. Let's have a look at your input XML:

```
<part>
    <name>
        Other names   
    </name>=
    <value> * Some  * other * Names ([[IUPAC]])
        <ext>
            <!--Irrelevant stuff-->
        </ext>
        * Last name
    </value>
 </part>
```

The parts you are interested in are child *text nodes* of the `value` element. In XPath, text nodes are identified with `text()` (in the same way as `*` identifies element nodes). You could get them by simply evaluating

```
//value/text()
```

but your question implies that there might be several `value` elements and that the selection has to do with the `name` element that precedes the `value` element.

---

Finally, there is perhaps something wrong with your Fiddle. Even `doc.evaluate("//*", doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)` returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias for helping me out AND explaining it in detail. Still I don't understand "As you can see, the expression returns two individual results". I read more about it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550652/multiple-string-results-for-an-xpath), looks like XPath 1.0 can't return two results. I understand how I would concatenate two results, but how do I get the second one? Updated the fiddle (thanks to Data Masseur's hint), thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @user3255061 XPath 1.0 can certainly select more than one result, but it cannot _join_ result strings, that's what Dimitre's answer means. If you do not get both results, you a) either are not using the correct JS function to select multiple nodes, or b) you do not store them in an appropriate data structure that can hold several items or c) you have all of the above correct, but only output the first result or d) your input document is actually different.

Answer (score 0):

If all you really want is the part name and no data from inside the value tags ("*no child nodes of value.*"), just use `/part/name[contains(text(), 'Other names')]`

If that's not what you want, please explain what you expect to see for the output.

edit below based on comments:

OK, I think you just had an extra period in your XPath string.

Try `//name[contains(text(), 'Other names')]/following-sibling::value[not(self)]/text()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @DataMasseur, also for the hint to describe my desired output. I updated my question. Your solution returns nothing though (http://jsfiddle.net/861yw8xc/), or am I doing something wrong? I'm a total newbie in xPath: Isn't the "*Last name" bit connected to the `<value>`-tag?

Comment: OK, looking at your fiddle, you added a parent template tag, which is why my answer didn't return anything.  My solution assumed part was the top level.  So for clarity, you want any values for name that DO NOT occur inside of a "value" tag?

Comment: As an aside, the XML in your fiddle is invalid, as the closing template tag is malformed.

Comment: Sorry for messing that up, I should have explained better. I've generally done a very poor job with that example, as there are both `<name>'s`s and "names" like "*other names". So the exact output I want to have is ** *Some *other *Names ([[IUPAC]]) * Last name_ **. Your solutions returns everything but _* Last name _. I've updated the fiddle - thanks for the hint and your patience. Any way of also getting the "* Last name"?